# ng-click working for all ng-repeat elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm getting the object from url and that is rendered in card view. In that card view when i click the ready button that the style is apply for all card view but it suppose to be apply for respective click. here is the code

```
<md-card md-image-no-fill flex-xs flex-gt-xs="30" style="border-radius:0px; max-width:23%" ng-repeat="x in getResponse">
  <md-card-header class="card-header" ng-class="{'card-header1':toggle}">

    <md-card-header-text class="card-header-text" >
        {{header_text}}
    </md-card-header-text>
  </md-card-header>

  <md-card-content class="card-content">
    Order Id:{{x.orderId}} </br>
    Order Amount:{{x.amount}}
  </md-card-content>
  <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="start center">
    <md-button style=" background-color:#A3506E;  margin-left:38%;" ng-click="delivered(x.id)" ng-style="btn_style">{{button}}</md-button>
  </md-card-actions>
</md-card>

Controller Logic
$scope.toggle = false;
    $scope.header_text="Marked As Accepted - Process Please";

    $scope.button="Ready";

    $scope.delivered=function(id){

      $scope.toggle=true;
      console.log("hello world");
      $scope.header_text="Dispatched Is it Delivered";
      $scope.button="Delivered";

      $scope.btn_style={
        "background-color":"Green",
        "margin-left":"38%"
      }

    }

$http.get('url').success(function(data) {
        $scope.getResponse = data;       
      })
      .error(function(data, status) {
        console.error('Repos error', status, data);
      })
  })
```

Comment: The style $scope.btn_style bound to the md-button directive is common to all and not specific to a particular item in the ng-repeat directive so you see that the style is applied to all elements after the button is clicked if you want to make it specific to an element then store the style for each element independently in the data source you're using in the ng-repeat directive and then in the ng-click directive's function update the style of the element that is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
<md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="start center">
    <md-button style=" background-color:#A3506E;  margin-left:38%;" ng-click="delivered(x.id,x)" 
               ng-style="x.btn_style">{{button}}</md-button> //<----changed this line
  </md-card-actions>


$scope.delivered=function(id,x){                             //<----changed

      $scope.toggle=true;
      console.log("hello world");
      $scope.header_text="Dispatched Is it Delivered";
      $scope.button="Delivered";

      x.btn_style={                                          //<----changed
        "background-color":"Green",
        "margin-left":"38%"
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply i've small query y do we give x.btn_style instead of $scope.btn_style. And also if click the button all the header text are changed for all card i want to change it for respective click.

Comment: $scope.header_text="New Order Accept Please";
    $scope.button="Ready";
    $scope.delivered=function(id,x){
      $scope.order="TFP3JAEHZKL";
      if(id==$scope.order) {                
       x.header_text = "Dispatched Is it Delivered";
       x.button = "Delivered";
        x.btn_style = {
          "background-color": "Green",
          "margin-left": "38%"
        }
        x.btn_style1 = {
          "padding-top": "0px",
          "background-color": "Green",
          "height": "25px"
        }
      }
    }

Comment: <md-card-header-text class="card-header-text">
        {{header_text}}
    </md-card-header-text>
  </md-card-header>

Comment: Instead of using `$scope`, you can use `x.property` inside of click event. Why?? Beccause i m passing x as a parameter.  `X` is your respectives object. So if now you hv problem with header, what you can do is `x.header_text='dispatched...'` n so on... it will only change header of current (passed) `x` object's `header_text` property